# Jquery Upgrade breaking parts of application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-ajax

We currently have asp.net mvc application that uses Jquery 1.12.3 and Jquery UI 1.11.1 versions. I am upgrading the jquery to latest versions 3.6.4 or 3.7 and jquery ui to 1.13.2. Ajax calls from client side  are not being triggered after the upgrade and console gives this error as below but nothing on application end. I tried all options but unable to figure out what needs to be changed here. Any pointers on how to fix the issue, is it the versions of jquery or some code mismatch to be accommodated for any version mismatches.

[image]